# Restarting redis do not restore bitset

Tags: redis, backup

I have saved a bitset in redis

```
setbit "ABC" 10 1
```

My configuration for redis have a save option

```
save 100 1
```

But when I restart the redis, this leads to all my set bits getting lost from my key "ABC".

Has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: How did you restart Redis? Note that depending on the signal you sent to the instance, the data are not saved.

Comment: @Eli: I'm using RDB persistent

Comment: @DidierSpezia: I checked the redis log file, it says that snapshot has been taken but on redis restart, I find a lot of in-consistencies

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem at all. You could try to use redis-rdb-tools to get a human readable representation of the content of the dump file: https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools

Comment: Try switching to AOF and see if that fixes your problem. Details at http://redis.io/topics/persistence.